# How to create JNLP dynamically and pass arguments using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, java-web-start, jnlp

I know the question might have come before as well but post Java 7u51 there have been significant changes. Since applet is almost dead now I need to convert one of my project's applet to a JNLP file which can be launched on client's machine. Any pointers as to how to do it using JSPs?? Do I need to sign JNLP and jars dynamically as well?? I am currently working on Java 7u80.

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page contentType="application/x-java-jnlp-file" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/security.tld" prefix="sec" %>

<%

response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");


String strFileName = (String) request.getAttribute("FileName");
HttpSession objHttpSession = request.getSession(false);
String strSessionId =    (String)objHttpSession.getAttribute(MWIConstants.SESSION_ID);
            if (!(objHttpSession.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(strSessionId)) || null == objHttpSession.getAttribute(MWIConstants.HELPER))
            {%>
                <logic:redirect forward="LOGIN"/>
            <%}


%>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.7+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/xyz/" href="appletjnlp.jsp">

<information>
<title>ImageViewer</title>
<vendor>Oracle and/or its affiliates.</vendor>
</information>

<resources>
<j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"   max-heap-size="256m"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/applet.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/one.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/two.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/three.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/four.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/five.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/six.jar"/>
<jar href="pages/applet/seven.jar"/>
</resources>

<applet-desc
documentbase="http://localhost:8080/mwi/pages/"
name="ImageViewer"
main-class="cdac.medinfo.mwt.imaging.imageviewer.ImageApplet"
width="300" 
height="300">
        <param name='targetVersion' value='1.7'>
        <PARAM name="boxbgcolor" value='silver'>
        <PARAM name="progressbar" value='true'>
        <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE='<%= strFileName %>'>
        <PARAM NAME="ContextPath" VALUE='<%= request.getContextPath()%>'>
        <PARAM NAME="ResponseObject" VALUE='<%=response%>'>
        <PARAM NAME="ServerName" VALUE='<%=request.getServerName()%>'>
        <PARAM NAME="Port" VALUE='<%= request.getServerPort()%>'>
 </applet-desc>

 <security>
 <all-permissions/>
 </security>

 <component-desc/>
 </jnlp>
```

Comment: This is rather easy once you realize that a JSP doesn't have to output HTML.

Comment: @EJP Right now I have dumped all JNLP XML content into a JSP along with some JSP code. The jars used as resources are signed manually and not at runtime. I feel lost after that. Any elaoboration will be helpful.

Comment: So you need to post what you have done and what problem you are experiencing wih it.

Comment: But not the problem. No question here to answer yet.

Comment: @EJP How to get this JNLP dynamically generated every time on user's request for a different file. All I am getting now is the title on the web page. I am new to this web start thing and I am not sure even if I am asking the right thing.